# Is an object that creates other objects bad program design in Java?

Tags: java

I have an instance of an object (Object1) whose constructor creates instances of other objects (Object2) and stores them in an ArrayList. Object2 has a static instancecount variable (among other static variables), and instances of Object2 depend on this instancecount. In a test program, I run a for loop where an instance of Object1 are created on each iteration, and then the reference to the instance of Object1 is reassigned a null value. My test program looks something like:

```
    for (...) {
        Object1 obj = new Object1(...); //which creates several Object2's
        obj.myMethod();
        obj = null;
    }
```

The problem is that instances of Object2 are not getting garbage collected at the end of each loop iteration, so the static instancecount variable of Object2 just grows and grows (along with memory usage) with every iteration. Is this to be expected? Is there a way to force the cleanup of the Object2 instances so that each loop has a fresh start? Is this a bad program design?

Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: 1) How do you know that the instances of Object2 are not being GC'd? 2) And what should this have to do with the instanceCount value? 3) You do understand that GC is not fully under your control. Just because an object has no references to it, does not mean that it will be GC'd now or in the near future unless the GC object decides it needs to be collected, such as when memory gets low.

Comment: It sounds like you want to have [weak references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to these objects. Whether or not that's good design is another matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Garbage collection works pretty reliable, so it won't leak memory or grow indefinitely.

But GC also only runs when the JVM thinks it needs to, so you cannot force it to run at the end of every iteration of your loop.

Having code that depends on when GC runs is bad code.

Also, I am not sure how you are managing the instance count. It is easy to increment it in a constructor, but when do you decrease it again? It certainly won't happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`static instancecount variable (among other static variables)`

Review Object2's static variables. If they are in anyway referencing an Object2 instance, that instance will never be garbage collected unless manually removed.

`an object (Object1) whose constructor creates instances of other objects (Object2) and stores them in an ArrayList`

And where is this ArrayList stored and when is it cleared? Try removing Object2 from this list in your for loop.

If you can show more of your code, it would be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that instances of Object2 are not getting garbage collected at the end of each loop iteration, ... . Is this to be expected?

Yes it is.  The default behaviour of a JVM is to run the garbage collector when it is most efficient to do so.  That typically means when the "new" space fills up.  The GC is certainly not "eager", and it does not try to reclaim objects as soon as they become unreachable.

> Is there a way to force the cleanup of the Object2 instances so that each loop has a fresh start?

You can call `System.gc()` as a hint to run the garbage collector NOW.  But the JVM can be configured to ignore the hint.

> Is this a bad program design?

It is usually bad design to call `System.gc()`.  Running the GC is relatively expensive, and running it frequently when it is not necessary (from an ergonomic perspective) is very wasteful.

It is always bad design to write code that depends on the GC running immediately.  Indeed, anything that requires the use of a custom `finalize()` should be treated with great suspicion.

---

I think that your real issue is this:

> .... so the static instancecount variable of Object2 just grows and grows (along with memory usage) with every iteration

This is true to a point.  But eventually, the JVM will decide that it is a good time to run the GC, and all of the objects will be reclaimed.  That's the way that GC works.

Your real problem is (I think) that you are uncomfortable with the fact that a significant amount of memory is needed to hold all of the garbage objects that haven't been reclaimed yet.  But the flip side to that is that the GC ... and your application ... runs faster if it has plenty of memory to play with.  Surprisingly, both allocation and reclamation are much faster than if the GC used (for instance) reference counting to ensure that objects are reclaimed ASAP.

---

The other thing to note is that you must be using a finalizer to decrement the instance counter.  This has the unfortunate side-effect of significantly increasing the GC overheads, and slowing the ultimate recycling of the objects.

(What happens is that the main GC notices that the object is finalizable, and adds it to a queue to finalized later.  The finalizable objects and any objects that are reachable are taken off the list of objects that can be immediately reclaimed. At a later point, the finalization thread  iterates over the queue, calling the `finalize` methods for each one.  If this results in objects becoming fully unreachable, they will be reclaimed on the next GC run.)

Comment: `System.gc()` does not run the garbage collector NOW.  It sets bits that suggest a full garbage collection be preformed, whenever the garbage collection thread eventually gets around to it.

Comment: @EdwinBuck - can you provide a source for that please.  My reading of the javadoc and other Oracle documentation is that it either runs the GC as soon as possible, or it is totally ignored.  At the very least, the behaviour will be JVM specific.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses everyone! I rewrote the code to not depend on the GC. Unfortunately, this meant manually clearing several static variables on each loop run. Something about this seems awkward, so I imagine that in the future I should be careful about code that runs factory objects/methods containing static variables in loops.

Here are the answers to some of the questions I received from you all. Again, thanks a lot!

Thilo: I increment the instancecount via a constructor, but don't decrease the instancecount. That seems like something that would be appropriate for a deconstructor, although these don't exist, right. What would be an appropriate way to decrement it?

Adrian: I tried clearing the ArrayList in the loop, but no success. The ArrayList is a field of Object1.

Stephen: It seems you just answered my question above about how to decrement instancecount, but as you implied, this adds unwanted overhead.

Chamini2: I tried calling System.gc() in the for loop before posting, but it doesn't want to run. Apparently this method is just a suggestion.